# How do I unescaped, string that has been escaped multiple times in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have spent close to an hour on this already, so this is a true case of hitting a wall.

For reasons beyond my control, an internal service I am using hands me a JSON that is in this form

```
    let dirty_string = r#"\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"val2\\\"}\""#;
```

Now obviously this does not look right. My plan it to take this and use `serde_json` to construct the appropriate struct but that does not work.

I have tried various ways to remove the multiple escapes.

I have tried various form of using replace

This

`let to_format = dirty_string.replace("\\\\", r#""#);`

gives this

`"\\\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"val2\\\"}\\\""` basically making the matter worse

This `let to_format = dirty_string.replace("\\", r#""#);` gives this

`"\"{\"key1\":\"val1\",\"key2\":\"val2\"}\""`

which looks like almost there, but does not work because when I try to parse it into the struct it fails

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Parsed {
    key1: String,
    key2: String
}

let to_struct: Parsed = serde_json::from_str(&to_format).unwrap();
dbg!(to_struct);

thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("invalid type: string \"{\", expected struct Parsed", line: 1, column: 3)', src/main.rs:440:62
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
```

So I will really appreciate help here.

How exactly can I successfully removing this annoying back slashes such that it becomes a valid json string that I can then parse to the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a JSON string that was again encoded as JSON, and finally had characters backslash-escaped (smells of PHP's `addslashes()`).  So you need to do these steps in order:

- Strip one set of backslashes, which will produce a new string.
- JSON-decode another String from the new one.
- Finally, JSON-deserialize into the struct.

For example:

```
use std::error::Error;

use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
struct Data {
    pub key1: String,
    pub key2: String,
}

fn stripslashes(s: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let mut n = String::new();

    let mut chars = s.chars();

    while let Some(c) = chars.next() {
        n.push(match c {
            '\\' => chars.next()?,
            c => c,
        });
    }

    Some(n)
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let dirty_string = r#"\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"val2\\\"}\""#;

    let s = stripslashes(&dirty_string).expect("stripslashes failed");
    let s: String = serde_json::from_str(&s)?;

    let data: Data = serde_json::from_str(&s)?;

    println!("{:?}", data);

    Ok(())
}
```

This outputs:

```
Data { key1: "val1", key2: "val2" }
```

Comment: slightly beating myself up for not figuring this out. How were you able to read whats going on from the string? You mentioned this is caused by a json string encoded as json?

Comment: @FinlayWeber Honestly, mostly just experience. You work with lots of different kinds of data formats and programming environments for long enough and you recognize patterns pretty quickly. And yes, the original data appears to have been a JSON-encoded object. The JSON string was then JSON-encoded again (as a string), and _that_ string then had all \ and `"` characters escaped. I have no idea why anyone would do all that, but I've seen far weirder stuff before.

Answer (score 2):

You can add quotes and put it through three iterations of `serde_json`:

```rs
let dirty_string = r#"\"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"val1\\\",\\\"key2\\\":\\\"val2\\\"}\""#;
let s: String = serde_json::from_str(&format!(r#""{}""#, dirty_string)).unwrap();
let s: String = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();
let value: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&s).unwrap();
println!("{value:#?}");
```

Comment: Interesting. How come this works? How come in the process of converting to String, the string gets properly formatted?

Comment: @FinlayWeber The escaping in your string is the same as the escaping in JSON, except strings in JSON are surrounded by quotes, so in order for serde_json to process it, you need to surround it in quotes. Note that the top-level value in JSON can be any type, not just Object. In this case, adding quotes makes it a JSON document consisting of one string.

Comment: I think the limitation with this approach is not it assumes the number of `serde_json::from_str` calls needed. it could be the case that the unescaping requires more